# Парсинг iframe CefSharp

Tags: c#, winforms, cefsharp

Возможно ли как то с помощью CefSharp показать на `panel` только `div/iframe` вместо целого сайта? В `iframe` находится график, который обновляется режиме онлайн

Comment: так загрузите контент по ссылке, с которой подгружается iframe, и готово.

Comment: @aepot ну так не получается

Comment: это многое объясняет

Comment: @aepot по ссылке загрузить не получается, когда пытаюсь, выдает пустую страницу, обворачивал в свой iframe, все равно та же проблема, я думаю что там что то дополнительно генериться с подвязкой скриптов, может быть

Comment: Смотрите трафик, куки, заголовки